# Sell a posts extra input fields - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've been searching, trying to find a plugin that can help me set a price for each of my posts extra input fields.

So, I have a property post type that has the default title, content and featured image fields. Then I have extra fields such as attachment, video. What I need is to initially deny access to each of those extra fields (individually) and only when the user buys the necessary access, will one or all of those fields become available. This must be done when the user is adding a new post and use WooCommerce for the payment.

A visual example:
[image]

Plugins I've tried:
 - [myCRED](https://mycred.me/) (only allows the sale of a whole post and not individual fields)
 - [Fields Monetization](https://templatic.com/directory-add-ons/tevolution-fields-monetization/) (uses packages, not allowing individual field pricing)
 - [Restrict Content](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-content/) (only allows the sale of complete posts)

If you guys know about any plugins that can achieve this, even if it requires some tweaking, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not your tried Advanced Custom Fields plugin?

Comment: My fields already exist as part of a theme.

Comment: i think it must me back end first and need to show front end right?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question but the fields for sale should be selected and priced in the backend. Then the frontend will show that payment is required for those fields as in my visual example.

Comment: Please at least tell me why, if you feel the need to down-vote. Otherwise whats the point?

Comment: ok, let's do it show me your website URL and where you would like to appear? Your questions going to confuse me

Comment: The website is not live yet, its still incomplete on a local server. If you can tell me which part confuses you, I'd be happy to clarify.

Comment: the screenshot you added to the questions is the front part and it is post or products?

Comment: Yes it is the front part and it is a post, no products. So the Attachment and Add Video sections are fields of the post.

Comment: The main reason that people **down voted your question** is (in the rules of stackOverFlow): *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."* … **StackOverFlow is a coding forum**, so mainly some code is expected in the questions…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I completely understand. Thanks for the explanation :) So it'd be better to post this in the WP section of stackexchange.

Comment: @Ragmah No Wordpress StackExchange is even worst as it's only for pure Wordpress (no plugins, no WooCommerce)… I don't know where you can post this, *may be on Super User*.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Ohh okay I see. I'll check Super User out then. Thanks again, you're awesome.